# Pass List<T> between objects or forms

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

How to pass object class MyForm property listings ClassN?(ClassN have no base class or interface). As an object of class MyForm will be able to access the members ClassN?

Purpose: to display in the ListView (or ObjectListView, or other) on the form information from different sources, automatically determining the number of columns (public properties with attributes (in the example below, it is not specified)). When the class **one**, I used:

```
private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BrightIdeasSoftware.Generator.GenerateColumns(this.olv, typeof(Class1));
}
```

How to implement such a generic?

---

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Class1> list1 = new List<Class1>();
        list1.Add(new Class1(1, "Word"));
        list1.Add(new Class1(2, "Excel"));
        list1.Add(new Class1(3, "Access"));

        List<Class2> list2 = new List<Class2>();
        list2.Add(new Class2(10, "Jhon", "City1"));
        list2.Add(new Class2(15, "Ruby", "City2"));
        list2.Add(new Class2(20, "William", "City3"));

        MyForm form = new MyForm();
        form.SetData(list1); // ?
    }
}

class MyForm
{
    List<T> data = // ?

    public void SetData<T>(List<T> data)
    {
        this.data = data; // ?
    }     
}

class Class1
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Class1(int id, string name)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}

class Class2
{
    public int Num { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public Class2(int num, string name, string address)
    {
        Num = num;
        Name = name;
        Address = address;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its unclear to me what you're looking for but I think all you are missing is making `MyForm` generic - `class MyForm<T>`

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are asking. However, if you mean that you currently have a class `MyForm` that was written specifically to handle `Class1` and now you want the extend the class so that it can handle both `Class1` and `Class2`, you're probably going to need two different form classes.

You've stated that `Class1` and `Class2` are completely independent classes, without a common base class or interface. Given that, there's no polymorphic way to have some single code operate on instances of the two different classes. (If all you cared about was the `Name` property, the one member that exists in both classes, maybe `dynamic` would work for you).

To minimize the extra work, you can create a single, generic base class that handles everything that is *not* specific to each of `Class1` and `Class2`. E.g.:

```
partial class MyForm<T> : Form
{
    List<T> data;

    public void SetData<T>(List<T> data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }  
}

partial class MyClass1Form : MyForm<Class1> { ... }
partial class MyClass2Form : MyForm<Class2> { ... }
```

In each of the derived classes, you'd then implement the code that is specific to each of `Class1` or `Class2`.

But note that the Visual Studio Winforms Designer has trouble dealing with classes that have generic base classes.

It is possible that you could abstract not the `Form` subclass itself, but rather an accessor/handler of the data, so that the single `MyForm` class could be used without confusing the Designer, and yet would still work with multiple data types. But without more context in your question, it's not possible to say for sure what that'd look like. It would depend entirely on how `MyForm` actually uses the passed-in list.